# Good query-document dataset for learning to rank algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, information-retrieval, information-extraction

Recently I started working on a learning to rank algorithm which involves feature extraction as well as ranking. Famous learning to rank algorithm data-sets that I found on Microsoft research website had the datasets with query id and Features extracted from the documents. Can someone suggest me a good learning to rank Dataset which would have query-document pairs in their original form with good relevance judgment ??.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alex Rogozhnikov keeps track of a few of datasets that you can use for learning to rank, check [his blog post](http://arogozhnikov.github.io/2015/06/26/learning-to-rank-software-datasets.html)

You can also use the [DBLP dataset](http://www.arnetminer.org/citation), which was also used in a Learning to Rank task, check this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.05132.pdf